# Need output column-wise from row-wise records

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
2015 Apr 20  15:29:49.128  [00]  0xB112  Reserved
    This packet is currently not supported.
```

I want like this

```
**timestamps**              |**hexstring**  |    **message**
2015 Apr 20  15:29:49.128   |0xB112         |  Reserved This packet is currently not supported.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use concat_ws() to concatenate any delimiter (e.g. '|') as given below in the query.
```

Input: 2015 Apr 20  15:29:49.128  [00]  0xB112  Reserved This packet is currently not supported.

```
select concat_ws('|', timestamps, hexstring, message) from tableName;
```

Output: 2015 Apr 20  15:29:49.128  | [00]  0xB112  | Reserved This packet is currently not supported.